# Windows, How come Diff.exe reports an error?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, diff, gnu

We have 3 files in 3 directories:

- d:\run.exe
- d:\temp\RunShortcut = d:\run.exe
- s:\temp\RunShortcut = d:\run.exe

The above 2 shortcut files are 433 bytes each and
shortcuts are present in directories d:\temp and s:\temp

All is ok with

```
Diff.exe -r -q d:\temp s:\temp
```

Now delete d:\run.exe (deleting the target) and do Diff again:

```
Diff.exe -r -q d:\temp s:\temp
```

Reports an error because the EXE is gone,
the Target is deleted, but the 2 files are same.

There is no difference between:

- d:\temp\RunShortcut
- s:\temp\RunShortcut

Why is Diff reporting an error when there is no difference?

Is there a switch in Diff.exe to ignore Target?

Is it wise to tell Diff to ignore Target?

I'm Using Windows XP and diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.7

--

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a switch in Diff.exe to ignore Target?

Yes.

> `--no-dereference`
>
> Act on symbolic links themselves instead of what they point to. Two
>   symbolic links are deemed equal only when each points to precisely the
>   same name.

Source [Comparing and Merging Files - Options to diff](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#diff-Options)

---

#### Is it wise to tell Diff to ignore Target?

Only you can answer that. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the LINK (url) to the Diff.exe that runs on Windows XP and Windows 7 and has the switch "--no-dereference"?  Diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.7 does not have a switch "--no-dereference".   The 2.8.7 GNU Diff help file is about 75 Lines long, but, does not have a switch "--no-dereference". http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/ gave version 3.6 with 944 files and it appears that none of the 944 files are for Windows XP.

Comment: @Joseph "This manual is for GNU Diffutils (version 3.6, 6 May 2017)"

Comment: Where to download Diffutils verison 3.6 for Windows XP?  What is the Link?     The 3.6 version I downloaded had 944 files.  And none of the 944 files appeared to be for XP.

Comment: @Joseph I don't have one. If you want a newer version than 2.8.7 you will need to upgrade your out of date operating system ...

Comment: In the new version of diffutils-3.6 there were 944 files and zero files were ".EXE" and zero files were ".COM".  

What is the LINK to get an Executable for diffutils-3.6?  

-